# Lost Session On Load Balance Server from http to https

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, web-applications

We are currently running an asp.net application with 3.5 framework, using a SQL 2008 back-end.  We have found that when we go from http to https we lose our session.  Basically you come in on Server01 in http, add an item to your cart go to the secure checkout page (https) and you are now on Serve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that on both servers the session is set to "StateServer" and that they both have the same state connection string:

Web.Config:

```
<sessionState mode="StateServer"
            stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424"
            cookieless="false"
            timeout="120"/>
```

This means all session info is stored in the database - not the process of the application itself.

Answer (score 1):

By default sessions are stored in memory on each individual server. So if you switch from one server to another you loose your session.

You need to configure your session to use a in memory session sever or a sql server.